# Проблемы при попытке вызова C# метода из Java плагина

Tags: java, c#, android, unity3d, плагин

У меня есть рабочее `android-приложение`, которое получает входящие уведомления и выводит их на экран с помощью текста... Я взял фрагмент кода и сделал плагин для `Unity`. Изначально я пытался вызывать метод который должен срабатывать при получении нового уведомления из `C#`, но позже по рекомендациям одного человека из данного сообщества я попытался вызвать `C#` метод из моего `Java-класса`, и передать ему 2 переменные, в которых и содержатся фрагменты входящего уведомления:

```java
public class ReceiveIncomingNotificationsAndPassThemToMyUnityAppClass extends NotificationListenerService {
    private final String UnityCallbackObject = "ReceiveIncomingNotifications";
    private final String UnityCallbackMethod = "Receive";
    Context context;
    public String title;
    public String text;


    @Override

    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        String ticker ="";
        if(sbn.getNotification().tickerText !=null) {
            ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        }
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        title = extras.getString("android.title");
        text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
        int id1 = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);
        Bitmap id = sbn.getNotification().largeIcon;

        if(id != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            id.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

        }
        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(UnityCallbackObject, UnityCallbackMethod, title);
        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(UnityCallbackObject, UnityCallbackMethod, text);


    }
}
```

Соответственно мой c# код выглядел так:

```
   public void Receive(string title, string text)
    {
    //   var plugin = new AndroidJavaClass("com.alexcompany.receiveincomingnotificationsandpassthemtomyunityapp.ReceiveIncomingNotificationsAndPassThemToMyUnityAppClass");

        Title = title;
        Text = text;
       //     Title = plugin.Get<string>("title");
        //    Text = plugin.Get<string>("text");
            TextForTitle.text = Title;
            TextForBody.text = Text;
        
    }
}
```

При этой реализации я не получал никаких ошибок в `logcat`, но и при получении нового уведомления в моем `Unity` приложении мой текст оставался пустым...

Дальше я решил сделать как тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944478/callback-listener-in-unity-how-to-call-script-file-method-from-unityplayeracti/41018028#41018028
и вот как стал выглядеть мой `Java-class`:

```java
public class ReceiveIncomingNotificationsAndPassThemToMyUnityAppClass extends NotificationListenerService {

    Context context;
    public String title;
    public String text;




    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn, PluginCallback callback) {
        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        String ticker ="";
        if(sbn.getNotification().tickerText !=null) {
            ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        }
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        title = extras.getString("android.title");
        text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
        int id1 = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);
        Bitmap id = sbn.getNotification().largeIcon;

        if(id != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            id.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

        }
  
        callback.Receive(title, text);


    }
}
```

так же был добавлен `Java interface`:

```java
public interface PluginCallback {
    public void Receive(String title, String text);
    
}
```

и теперь вот как стал выглядеть мой `C#` код:

```
public class AndroidPluginCallback : AndroidJavaProxy
{

    public AndroidPluginCallback() : base("com.alexcompany.receiveandpassnotificationsyomyunityapplibrary.PluginCallback") { }
    public string Title;
    public string Text;
    public TextMeshPro TextForTitle;
    public TextMeshPro TextForBody;

    public void Receive(string title, string text)
    {

       TextForTitle = GameObject.Find("TextForTitle").GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
        TextForBody = GameObject.Find("TextForBody").GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
        Title = title;
        Text = text;
        TextForTitle.text = Title;
        TextForBody.text = Text;
    }
}
```

И еще один `C#` код:

```
public class ReceiveIncomingNotificationsFromJavaClass : MonoBehaviour
{

   
    public void Start()
    {
        AndroidJavaObject pluginClass = new AndroidJavaObject("com.alexcompany.receiveandpassnotificationsyomyunityapplibrary.ReceiveIncomingNotificationsAndPassThemToMyUnityAppClass");
        pluginClass.Call("onNotificationPosted", new AndroidPluginCallback());
    }
 
}
```

и за одно `Android Mainfest` из моего плагина сюда:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alexcompany.receiveandpassnotificationsyomyunityapplibrary">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <application>
        <service
            android:name="com.alexcompany.receiveandpassnotificationsyomyunityapplibrary.ReceiveIncomingNotificationsAndPassThemToMyUnityAppClass"

            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />

            </intent-filter>

        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

При этой реализации я не получал никаких ошибок в `logcat`, но и при получении нового уведомления в моем `Unity` приложении мой текст оставался пустым...
В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант:

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(UnityCallbackObject, UnityCallbackMethod, title);
```

здесь вы пытаетесь вызвать метод `Receive`, передав ему **один** параметр `title`, но сам метод объявили с **двумя** параметрами - куда уходит вызов неизвестно, но точно не в ваш метод.

Второй вариант: то же, только в обратном направлении: `onNotificationPosted` у вас с двумя параметрами, а вызвать пытаетесь с одним. Плюс вы изменили сигнатуру метода и система его не вызовет никогда - вы вообще не должны вызывать его сами. Вместо этого можно объявить колбек статическим полем сервиса, из шарпа передать его экземпляр этому полю, на java проверить валидность и вызвать. Что-то вроде:

```
public class ReceiveIncomingNotificationsAndPassThemToMyUnityAppClass extends NotificationListenerService {

    private static PluginCallback callback;

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        if (callback != null) {
            Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
            String title = extras.getString("android.title");
            String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
            callback.Receive(title, text);
        }
    }

    public static void setCallback(PluginCallback c) {
        callback = c;
    }
}
```

```
public class ReceiveIncomingNotificationsFromJavaClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Start()
    {
        AndroidJavaClass serviceClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.alexcompany.receiveandpassnotificationsyomyunityapplibrary.ReceiveIncomingNotificationsAndPassThemToMyUnityAppClass");
        serviceClass.CallStatic("setCallback", new AndroidPluginCallback());
    }
}
```

P.S. с `c#` и юнитами знаком очень поверхностно - скорее всего код не совсем корректный и есть более правильное решение.

Comment: Здравствуйте, woesss! Спасибо за Ваш ответ! Считаю нужным ответить на Ваш вопрос: не чувствую я себя уверенно ни в C# ни в Java, так как занимаюсь программированием от силы месяцев пять - думаю это можно понять по моим вопросам... Помню я Ваш комментарий о том что мне нужно прочитать книгу по Java... Вот начал читать "Философия Java"... Параллельно уроки по c# смотрю... Вот и приходится задавать вопросы что-бы понять как это должно работать... Еще раз Огромное Вам Спасибо! =)

Comment: Ну я так и понял. Просто вы взялись за сложную задачу, требующую знаний сразу двух языков: `java` и `C#`; и двух SDK: `Android`  и `Unity`. При этом спотыкаетесь на базовых вещах, таких как сигнатура метода. Я в ответе пропустил статики - сейчас должно быть правильно. Если у вас логи пустые, но ничего не работает - то скорее всего ошибки перехватывают юниты, поищите как включить вывод логов - так будет проще понимать что не так сделано. Так же на время отладки желательно обложить всё логами, чтобы понимать какой код срабатывает, а до какого вообще не доходит.

Comment: Доброго вечера Вам woesss! Попробовал использовать Ваш код) никаких ошибок не получаю в logcat - что со стороны unity что со стороны Javа... В то же время ничего у меня нету на экране при получении уведомления... Конечно нужно еще уделить время этой задаче)) может использовать первый способ? без Java interface? или может еще попробовать проверить само срабатывания методов что на стороне java что на стороне unity - в logcat первым делом при срабатывании метода что-то выводить)) а если ничего не появится в logcat то и метод не срабатывает))

Comment: Я бы пощупал сам сервис для начала. Где-то попадалось на глаза, что для чтения уведомлений нужно явно ручками дать на это разрешение вашему приложению в настройках аппарата.

Comment: после того как я не понял что Вы имели ввиду под словами "пощупал сам сервис"(ведь я взял его из моего java приложения) я пошел и все же добавил парочку сообщений мне в logcat во время вызова моего java метода, и понял что при получении уведомления я не получаю моего сообщения в logcat а значит и мой метод не срабатывает... Нужно попробовать проделать то же самое но только уже с моим java приложением которое я сделал в android studio, и все же более детально осмотреть его Android Manifest. Завтра отпишу=)

Comment: Здравствуйте, woesss! Вы были правы! нужно было просто вручную разрешить моему приложению читать уведомления! Большое Вам спасибо за Ваши ответы и комментарии!!! ```=)```